# Multiple Inserts from a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very complex CTE that has hundreds of lines of code.

```
    ;WITH Data_alert
    AS (

    )
```

I like to do an insert into a variable table from the results of CTE Data_alert and then do another insert into a database table.

From what I see it may not be possible unless if I append another CTE to the first one.

as such:

```
    WITH Data_alert
    AS (

    ),
    Data_alert2 AS
    (

    )
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: *"From what I see it may not be possible unless if I append another CTE to the first one."* Why not? Where did you see this? You can define multi CTEs in a single statement, yes; I do it all the time.

Comment: You can insert into 2 different tables with an OUTPUT clause of INSERT

Comment: An [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might help, but your question is vague enough that it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a complex query that you want to refer to multiple times, then you likely want a temporary table of some sort:

```
WITH Data_alert AS (
      . . . 
     )
SELECT *
INTO #Data_alert
FROM Data_alert;
```

You can then re-use the temporary table in multiple queries.

From a performance perspective, this guarantees that the underlying complex code is executed only once.  In addition, you can add indexes for further performance gains.

From a processing perspective, this ensures that different steps in your script see the same data, even if the underlying data changes.

Comment: Thank you. what I want to do is insert into @Data_Input and then also use CDE Data_alert to insert into another table. As such, I like to make multiple inserts from CDE Data_alert.